# Updating record in database is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function update_team($data){
    $this->db->where('id',$_SESSION['id']);
    $this->db->update('team',$data);
    $this->db->last_query();
    var_dump($data);
}
```

and here is the controller

```
public function update_kontak(){
    $data = array (
        'nama_lengkap' => $this->input->post('nama_lengkap'),
        'kelamin' => $this->input->post('jk'),
        'tempat_lahir' => $this->input->post('tempat_lahir'),   
    );
    $this->User_models->update_team($data);
}
```

even when i use `$this->db->last_query();` its always show a blank page

Comment: regarding the blank page. it seems there is some error on your page other than the code you posted. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors","ON");` and check if you see any error.

Comment: also `echo` and check if you get value in `$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: `$this->db->last_query();` won't print anything you need to do `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: did you checked that you are getting id from session using `$_SESSION['id']` ? Debug proper, check that you are getting id from sesion.

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); then check

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it, you are doing an `UPDATE` which is not going to return any results. You perhaps need to `SELECT` some data to display?

Comment: He is any way not looking for or checking for a return value. And also if the requirement is of UPDATE, SELETing data wont help much